# Find network interface that is communicating with gateway without using PING/ ICMP or UDP

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I have a RHEL client machine which has to get data from the RHEL server machine at the time of booting up.

The IP address of the server is known.
The gateway which has to be used by the client machine is known.
The client machine has multiple network interfaces. All may not be up at the same time or all may be connected to different networks.
I need to determine which network interface has to be used.

I know that this can be easily done using the "ping" or "traceroute".
The issue is *ICMP* protocol is disabled both at the client end as well as the server end.
ICMP has been disabled due to security concerns.
ICMP may be disabled at machine level or it may be disabled for the whole network.

In otherword, I need to find a way that can give me if two ip's are communicating if ICMP is disabled.

Also, I have to use this result in my script, which I am writing in bash, to set the network of the client machine.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to know the NIC that will be used?  The kernel is usually pretty good at figuring that out for you.  You could always try asking the kernel with `ip route get <dest IP>` to see how it would try to send a packet to the dest IP--though if routing is broken down the line the packet might not make it, but that's what the kernel would try to do anyway

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I meant by I have to know the interface is that I have the list of interfaces but I have to find out which one is connected to the gateway that I have to use, without using ICMP/ ping. I have to setup the network manually after I find the Interface that I can use.

Comment: Ah, so you have no DHCP, you need to figure out which of the NICs should manually assign an address in the given space?  If so you could try running `tcpdump` and see which NIC sees traffic in the given space, but if it's a quiet network you might not find things too quickly.  Do you need to do this programatically?  (If not, a different Stack Exchange network might be better for this question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the ip with ARP try using `arping` command